# difficulty with an sql query using Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

the question:

Find the title of the books whose keyword contains the last 3 characters of the bookgroup of the book which was booked by "Mr. Karim".

I am trying to do it like this:

```
SELECT Title 
FROM Lib_Book 
WHERE BookKeywords LIKE '%(SELECT BookGroup FROM Lib_Book WHERE BookId=(SELECT BookId from Lib_Booking, Lib_Borrower WHERE Lib_Booking.BId=Lib_Borrower.BId AND Lib_Borrower.BName = 'Mr. Karim'))%';
```

from the part after % upto the end returns me an answer which is 'programming'. so i need to indicate the BookKeyword as '%ing%'. How can i do that?

**the tables are huge so i hvnt written those here..if anyone need to those plz lemme know...thnx

Comment: what you probably want is LIKE '%' + (SELECT .... ) + '%'

Comment: i have just tried it like :                                        SELECT Title FROM Lib_Book WHERE BookKeywords LIKE '%'+(SELECT BookGroup FROM Lib_Book WHERE BookId=(SELECT BookId from Lib_Booking, Lib_Borrower WHERE Lib_Booking.BId=Lib_Borrower.BId AND Lib_Borrower.BName = 'Mr. Karim'))+'%';   it gives error as Invalid Number

Comment: Actually, if it's the **last** three characters then you probably want ...`like '%ing'` - no trailing `%`. (Otherwise, you will get anything *containing* `ing`, not just anything *ending* `ing`).

Comment: well what i understand is that the last 3 character of the resulting BookGroup from the subQuery should be there in the required books' Keyword....plz correct me if i'm wrong...and how m i going to mean that '%ing' where i need to retrive that ing from the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic concept down, although it's not possible to process a `SELECT` statement inside a `LIKE` clause (and I'd probably shoot the RDBMS developer who allowed that - it's a **GAPING HUGE HOLE** for SQL Injection).  Also, you're likely to have problems with multiple results, as your 'query' would fail the moment Mr. Karim had borrowed more than one book.

I'd probably start by attempting to make things run off of joins (oh, and never use implicit join syntax):

```
SELECT d.title
FROM Lib_Borrower as a
JOIN Lib_Booking as b
ON b.bId = a.bId
JOIN Lib_Book as c
ON c.bookId = b.bookId
JOIN Lib_Book as d
ON d.bookKeywords LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(c.bookGroup, LENGTH(c.bookGroup) - 3) + '%'
WHERE a.bName = 'Mr. Karim'
```

Please note the following caveats:

1. This will get you all titles for all books with similar keywords to **all** borrowed books (from all 'Mr. Karim's).  You may need to include some sort of restrictive criteria while joining to `Lib_Booking`.
2. The column `bookKeywords` seems potentially like a multi-value column (would need example data).  If so, your table structure **needs** to be revised.
3. The use of `SUBSTRING()` or `RIGHT()` will invalidate the use of inidicies in joining to the `bookGroup` column.  There isn't much you can necessarily do about that, given your requirements...
4. This table is not internationalization safe (because the `bookGroup` column is language-dependant parsed text).  You may find yourself better served by creating a `Book_Group` table, a `Keywords` table, and a cross-reference `Book_Keywords` table, and joining on numerical ids.  You may also want language-keyed `Book_Group_Description` and `Keyword_Description` tables.  This *will* take more space, and *probably* take more processing time (increased number of joins, although potentially less textual processing), but give you increased flexibility and 'safety'.

Comment: Re #1, The title says Oracle.